# Is there a way to stop comment_node_view from firing?

Tags: comments

I need to use the [Commentsblock module](http://drupal.org/project/commentsblock), but it is turning out to be pretty buggy.  I've got an issue in the queue with a patch for comments not displaying for anonymous users.

Now I've got a second issue posted about how paging is broken, but I'm stumped on how to fix it so wanted to see if anyone else had an idea.

Here is the issue: http://drupal.org/node/1513910

My question is: Is there a way to prevent the comment_node_view function from executing?

Or....should I be going about this an entirely different way (backup plan is to use Views to display comments in a block, but I can't think of a way to respect threading so would like to avoid that if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) and stop the hook being run for the comment module:

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_view') {
    unset($implementations['comment']);
  }
}
```

Once you clear the cache `comment_node_view()` won't be called any more.

Comment: Ah-mazing!  Thanks, Clive.  I hadn't seen that hook before but it did the trick perfectly.  Going to add a patch to the issue queue with it in place.