# How to hide comments below the node, but not close them?

Tags: 7, comments

Аctually I want to list comments for nodes myself (by Views, for example), so I need to hide standard comments list from core comment module.
I can do it like that:

```
  unset($node['comments']['comments']);
```

But it will not prevent DB query for comments.
So I found some crazy ways to trick the comments module. For example, to set fake `$node->preview` property, or to create new view mode and overwrite standard `node/%node` callback.

Is it really so difficult to hide comments below the node but still allow to add new comment, or I missed something?

### Update about “Hidden” option

What about “Hidden” value for the content type:
I need close/open behaviour for my comments. But if I set “Hidden” for my content type, my new content pieces are set to “Comments closed” instead of hidden ([here is the code](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/4d4080b17681ae674e10c077b72d00f0b1544e0c:/modules/comment/comment.module#l1210)).
Another problem is that user with permission to “post comments” can't add a comment, if comments are hidden ([here is the code](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/4d4080b17681ae674e10c077b72d00f0b1544e0c:/modules/comment/comment.module#l2215)).
So I can't get the idea.

### Answer

Solution found with [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7). Thanks a lot!

Comment: its easy... edit the content type, under comment settings select "Hidden". this will hide your comments

Comment: @subhojit777 OP want to prevent DB query i think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In modules/comment/comment.module we can see that hook_node_view() (comment_node_view()) is running on line 614. This is where the functions are firing to load all comments and attach them to the node. The first 2 sets of if () { ... } appear to be handling the add comment form and action link. Then the final block of code is finally adding the comments, which I believe is what you're actually most concerned about hiding, and I assume you want this skipped for performance reasons:

```
// Only append comments when we are building a node on its own node detail
// page. We compare $node and $page_node to ensure that comments are not
// appended to other nodes shown on the page, for example a node_reference
// displayed in 'full' view mode within another node.
if ($node->comment && $view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node) && empty($node->in_preview)) {
  $node->content['comments'] = comment_node_page_additions($node);
}
```

I think this code is silly, because comment module should not be dependent on any particular hardcoded view mode. Hopefully this will change and become a setting in the UI.

Regardless, I've found a similar post that might interest you: [Is there a way to stop comment_node_view from firing?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/is-there-a-way-to-stop-comment-node-view-from-firing/27406)

Basically you're wanting to use hook_module_implements_alter() to stop the comment module from being able to fire off hook_node_view(). Here is what you need to add to your custom module:

```
function hook_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_view') {
    unset($implementations['comment']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially for `hook_module_implements_alter`!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use hide() in your template file, or hook_preprocess_node():

```
hide($content['comments']);
```

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28428/how-to-hide-comments-below-the-node-but-not-close-them/51061#comment27749_28428