# how to hide particular comment programmatically

Tags: 7, hooks, comments

not sure why:

```
function MY_MODULE_comment_view_alter(&$build) {
    $build['#comment'] -> status = 0;    
}
```

does not work. It displays comment on the red background, however comment is still visible for all users with 'view comments' rights. What I would like to achieve is simply hide comment so it's not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve this by adding a `comment_post_render` callback function to the build that outputs nothing:

```
function MY_MODULE_comment_view_alter(&$build) {
  $build['#post_render'][] = 'MY_MODULE_comment_post_render';
}

function MY_MODULE_comment_post_render() {
  // Nothing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this -

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_view') {
    unset($implementations['comment']);
  }
}
```

Taken from the answer of a question here - [Is there a way to stop comment_node_view from firing?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/is-there-a-way-to-stop-comment-node-view-from-firing/27406)